# OpenFin child window not visible

Tags: reactjs, openfin

I'm new to openFin. I have followed the steps mentioned in the video lecture(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4268gZfUYM&ab_channel=OpenFinTech) to create a child window but  getting a weird issue. I could see the success callback being called but not able to see the child window. Can you please let me know when this happens and how to make my child window visible.

OpenFinJS code to create a Child window:
[image]

Code where I call the above function:
[image]

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You are creating an Application, not a Window

In OpenFin, new Application creates a new render process, and you do need to call .run() on an Application after it's created. Take a look @ the tutorial code [here](http://cdn.openfin.co/jsdocs/stable/tutorial-application.constructor.html), specifically the success callback.

- Windows are autoShow: false by default & do not require a UUID

So the good news is, there's not much code to change to make this an OpenFin Window. The same tutorial but for Window is [here](http://cdn.openfin.co/jsdocs/stable/tutorial-window.constructor.html) with the code below.

```
var win = new fin.desktop.Window(
{
    name: "openFinWindow",
    url: "http://openfin.co",
    defaultWidth: 600,
    defaultHeight: 400
},
function() {
    win.show();
},
function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating window:", error);
}
);
```

UUID's are for identifying Apps/Render Processes so you wouldn't include that in here. Windows require a **name** and **url**. the defaults in the Window Options object aren't necessary. By default, autoShow is set to false. In the tutorial, show() is called on the object in the success callback. You can also set autoShow: true - depending on whether you want to create the window first.